# When is the group abelian?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

Let $1 \rightarrow H \rightarrow G\rightarrow K\rightarrow 1$ be an exact sequence such that $H$ and $K$ be abelian groups. When one can say that $G$ is abelian. One condition is that if the section from $K$ to $G$ is a homomorphism, then $G$ is direct product of $H$ and $K$. Is there anything that guarantees for $G$ to be abelian?

Comment: $1 \rightarrow H \rightarrow G\rightarrow K\rightarrow 1$ basically means that $H\to G$ is, up to isomorphism, an inclusion of a normal subgroup, and $K$ is (isomorphic to) $G/H$.

Answer (score 1):

The [direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product) of abelian groups is again abelian...